# Converting varchar to datetime2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I did an import from a flat file. I couldn't import the `datetime` column properly so I specified it temporarily as a `varchar(50)`. Now I want to convert it to the `datetime2` format. However when doing so I get the error -

> Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character
>   string.

The data that is currently in my `varchar(50)` column looks like this:

```
2008-04-02-16.43.32.179530
2009-01-12-20.15.41.936632
2009-02-18-16.54.49.071662
```

What's the best way to convert it to `datetime2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty

```
;WITH T(YourCol) As
(
SELECT '2008-04-02-16.43.32.179530' union all
SELECT '2009-01-12-20.15.41.936632' union all
SELECT '2009-02-18-16.54.49.071662'
)
SELECT CAST(
            STUFF(REPLACE(
                          STUFF(YourCol,11,1,'T')
                  ,'.',':')
            ,20,1,'.')
        AS DATETIME2)
FROM T
```

Comment: I should probably mention that I have several thousands of dates so writing a SELECT for each one would be painful.

Comment: My code doesn't do a `SELECT` for each one. It just use a common table expression with your 3 rows of example data for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Gotcha, and looking at the query it's a matter of replacing the delimiters with appropriate ones.

Comment: Yes. Actually the middle `stuff` might need to be `STUFF(YourCol,11,1,'T')` instead of `STUFF(YourCol,11,1,' ')` to be guaranteed to work regardless of regional settings. Not sure on that one at the moment but I'll edit that change regardless as that is ISO format.

Comment: Looks like it worked, I also changed `CAST` to `CONVERT`, specified the `datetime2` format in the beginning and removed `AS DATETIME2`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not a recognized timestamp format. It's close to ODBC Canonical format, but not quite. You'll have to do some string manipulation.

If you take the first 10 characters, that's the date in ODBC Canonical (yyyy-mm-dd) format, no changes needed. That's easy enough: `LEFT(dateAsStringColumn, 10)`. Now, you need characters 12 through 19 (skipping the dash between date and time), but with the "." replaced by ":". Lastly, tack on characters 20-26 verbatim. Convert that whole thing to a Datetime2 using style 21 (ODBC Canonical with milliseconds).

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, LEFT(myColumn, 10) + " " + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(myColumn, 12, 8), ".", ":") + RIGHT(myColumn, 7), 21) as DateFromString FROM myTable
```